# GNU screen freeze session if SSH is not connected

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, java, xmpp

I have a dedicated server (Inmotion) running a **Java XMPP server** through a `screen` session to keep it alive. Sometimes, after a long period, the execution of this Java XMPP server freeze and then when I connect to the SSH and reattach the `screen` session to see what is wrong, the execution defreeze itself and execute everything pending (send pending messages, queries to the DB, etc.) and it goes back to normal operation.

Note that I do nothing, I just connect to the SSH and reattach the `screen` session to read the output.

The period for this to happen is variable, sometimes hours, sometimes days later.

**What can I do to avoid this behavior?**